# Optimizing bit-waste for custom data encoding

Tags: algorithm, optimization, encoding

I was wondering what's a good solution to make it so that a custom data structure took the least amount of space possible, and I've been searching around without finding anything.

The general idea is I may have a some kind of data structure with a lot of different variables, integers, booleans, etc. With booleans, it's fairly easy to use bitmasks/flags. For integers, perhaps I only need to use 10 of the numbers for one of the integers, and 50 for another. I would like to have some function encode the structure, without wasting any bits. Ideally I would be able to pack them side-by-side in an array, without any padding.

I have a vague idea that I would have to have way of enumerating all the possible permutations of values of all the variables, but I'm unsure where to start with this.

Additionally, though this may be a bit more complicated, what if I have a bunch of restrictions such as not caring about certain variables if other variables meet certain criteria. This reduces the amount of permutations, so there should be a way of saving some bits here as well?

Example: Say I have a server for an online game, containing many players. Each player. The player struct stores a lot of different variables, level, stats, and a bunch of flags for which quests the player has cleared.

```
struct Player {
    int level; //max is 100
    int strength //max is 
    int int // max is 500
    /* ... */
    bool questFlag30;
    bool questFlag31;
    bool questFlag32;
    /* ... */
};
```

and I want to have a function that takes an vector of `Player`s called `encodedData encode(std::vector<Player> players)` and a function decodeData which returns a vector from the encoded data.

Comment: The question is too broad as it stands. We need more details. Currently the question is formed as asking for opinions, so there is no way that one answer could be viewed as THE answer to the question. Ask the question with enough details so that there can exist THE answer to the question.

Comment: @Dialecticus, My issue is that I don't know where to start. My issue *is* broad, and there may be many solutions, so I'm fine with opinions so long as it points me in the right direction. I guess I could update with a concrete example though.

Comment: The simple solution is to count the number of bits needed for each member of the `struct`. For example, a member with range 0 to 100 needs 7 bits. Range 0 to 500 needs 9 bits. A boolean needs 1 bit. For the output, you'll need an array of bytes, a byte index, and a bit index. Then you need to write a function `putbits(uint32_t value, int bitcount)` that appends the given value to the output.

Comment: @user3386109 Almost perfect -- there's still some bits that can be squeezed out, say I have 10 integers 0-100, that's 27 bits wasted per variable that could be used elsewhere.  But it's a good, simple solution.

Comment: It's not 27 **bits** per variable (you only need 7 bits to begin with), it's 27 **unused values** per variable. The number of bits needed to encode 0-100 is log2(101) = 6.66 bits. So there's 0.34 bits wasted. If the 10 integers are stored in separate bytes, that's 10 bytes. Using 7 bits per integer, you've got a total of 70 bits, which fit into 9 bytes, saving one byte. Using the theoretically perfect 6.66 bits, you've got a total of 66.6 bits, which still requires 9 bytes. So theoretic perfection saves nothing in your example.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, sorry. I meant unused values. It's not very significant, but in a larger example, it could add up, saving 5~10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with; it's not perfect, but it's something:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <assert.h>


/* Data structure for packing multiple variables, without padding */
struct compact_collection {

    std::vector<bool> data;

    /* Returns a uint32_t since we don't want to store the length of each variable */
    uint32_t query_bits(int index, int length) {
        std::bitset<32> temp;
        for (int i = index; i < index + length; i++) temp[i - index] = data[i];
        return temp.to_ulong();
    };

    /* */
    void add_bits(int32_t value, int32_t bits) {
            assert(std::pow(2, bits) >= value);
        auto a = std::bitset<32>(value).to_string();
        for (int i = 32 - bits; i < 32; i++) data.insert(data.begin(), (a[i] == '1'));
    };

};

int main() {
    compact_collection myCollection;
    myCollection.add_bits(45,6);
    std::cout << myCollection.query_bits(0,6);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```